# sql query from another query's result that is out of scope

Tags: php, mysql, sql

A very long and perhaps a simple question, but my brain is fried and I cannot process this logic currently.

There is a database I *have* to use, unfortunately. User #1 gives information about a company, component, and finally questions to answer. It then dumps this data into a database. Rather than store them in 1 table, or well defined relational tables it stores them in separate tables with little to no relationships.

*Now the problem, how to retrieve these questions*

So User#2 must then answer these questions. User #2 supplies the company name which I must then query for the id of (it's auto incremented and only relation to component & questions), then supplies the name of the component which I again must query the id of (it's auto incremented and the only relation to the questions). Then I must query for all questions with the given component and company id's (because obviously it is the only clear unique identifier). So, ready to kill yourself? Great! Lets look at the code!

**note the line that says !!!<-- goes out of scope after the loop is finished**

```
 <?php
 require_once 'connect.php';

 //$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
 $company_name = 'Some Company';
 $company_id_query = "SELECT * FROM company_mast WHERE company_name = '".$company_name."'";

 if ($query_run = mysql_query($company_id_query)) {
     if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) == NULL) {
        echo ('No results found');
     } else {
            while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $company_id = $query_row['id'];         

            echo ('company id: '.$company_id); // !!!<-- goes out of scope after the loop is finished
         }
     }
 }

 $component_name = 'Some Component';
 $component_id_query = "SELECT * FROM component_mast WHERE component_name = '".$component_name."' AND company_id = '".$company_id."'";

 if ($query_run = mysql_query($component_id_query)) {
     if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) == NULL) {
        echo ('No results found');
     } else {
        while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $component_id = $query_row['id'];           

            echo ('component id: '.$component_id); 
         }
     }
 }
 $questions = '';


 ?>
```

For those of you who have read all of that, thank you. Now my problem is obviously the 2nd query for component id will never work because the original result from the company id has gone out of scope. However I suck at `PHP` and I do not know another way to get said query result. 
So the big question is, ***How do I grab that result and store it so that it does not go out of scope?***

Hold all death threats and thank you for any answers.. especially ones that don't require me to use this ridiculous logic.

**Afterthought**

Could a `Join` statement solve all these problems?

Comment: Is this all the code, or did you trim it down for posting here? (It makes a difference. You `SELECT *...`, but in this code you use only the id number. Suboptimal SELECT statement, or trimmed code?

Comment: for now full code, in the finished product trimmed. I'm testing this on a local server with only 1 real answer, the live server has many many fields and will need a more optimized query

Comment: Also, it looks like you're going to be **WIDE** open to SQL Injection (`$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];`, plus the concatenation to the query).  Look up parameterized queries (and there's examples for PHP all over SO).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse oh absolutely, there is no escape_string, there is nothing. This is far from the finished product, I just need this to work for now. Finished implementations will have injection protection

Comment: @IrishWhiskey: Unless you mean "I will use either mysqli prepared statements or PDO prepared statements, not mysql_*() functions in the finished version", you're heading in the wrong direction. (See below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do, but maybe not the *right* thing to do: initialize $company_id in a "wider" scope.

```
 $company_id = "";    
 if ($query_run = mysql_query($company_id_query)) {
     if (mysql_num_rows($query_run) == NULL) {
        echo ('No results found');
     } else {
            while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $company_id = $query_row['id'];         

            echo ('company id: '.$company_id); // !!!<-- goes out of scope after the loop is finished
         }
     }
 }
```

Now, without knowing your data and your database structure better, I'd hesitate a little to recommend this. Your database and your loop might allow multiple id numbers for a company like "Shell Oil". Your loop would leave the *last* one of those in $company_id, and that *might* not be what you want.

Also, I initialized it to an empty string. That, too, *might* not be what you want.

It's quite possible that a single query with a JOIN clause would return everything you need.

---

After a quick glance, a join along these lines might work.

```
select c1.*, c2.*
from company_mast c1
inner join component_mast c2
        on c1.company_id = c2.company_id
where c2.component_name = ?
  and c1.company_id = ?
```

For better answers, *always* include CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements. Also, switch to either

- [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

and use prepared statements ([mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)).

Comment: I like the join clause, I think that's the ticket. I'm researching it now. If you would rather supply a query on the JOIN, joining the tables into one with component_id & company_id that would be fantastic. Also the company_id will be set using a POST method obviously from user input. It will not be hard coded

Comment: Thanks, I will attempt this solution. Double thanks for the msqli & PDO suggestions.

Comment: I slightly altered the statement, and now I need to alter it again using PDO. Thanks for all the help, maybe a second wind will allow me to continue working on this